Setting vendorchunk to true is not splitting vendor.js
As per this article - Reduce Vendor.js file size in Angular 8
If we set vendorChunk to true , the vendor.js file will get split. But this is not working.
vendor.js
I want to split the vendor.js to multiple small files. So that the browser will load them simultaneously.
I set vendorchunk to true. This is my production configuration:-

  "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,

But still the vendor.js file is 7 MB.  Please help.
